# How do I stop the Intercept Calls to DirectX

Tags: directx, dll-injection

I have read an article titled *[Intercept Calls to DirectX with a Proxy DLL](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/directx/directx8/article.php/c11453/Intercept-Calls-to-DirectX-with-a-Proxy-DLL.htm)*, it uses a DLL Proxy intercept call and can get overlay for DirectX.

I am writing some DirectX applications and do not want other people changing it through this method. How can I prevent this?

Can I do it by checking the original DLL, and how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

"Easiest" way to detect if it's a proxy or not would be to determine the path of the loaded d3d9.dll, calculate hash and compare it with stored hashes. But this would work only in cases where they let your application load the d3d9 proxy dll and not in cases they hook/inject.

Answer (score 0):

Just detect d3d9.dll(all DX dlls) file in youre application working directory and if it's there  then someone trying to proxy. It's easy to implement. Anyway you can't make something 100% protected so anything more complex than this just don't worth time invested :)
I managed to get data from all games with [3D Ripper DX](http://www.deep-shadows.com/hax/3DRipperDX.htm) and they have multimillion budget :)

Comment: thank you, JAre. If I detect d3d9.dll, How do I check it version or  feature? Can you tell me some articles about it?

Comment: @wenz as i understand to intercept calls (for example to d3d9.dll) you need to put proxy "d3d9.dll" in application directory and since applications (and DX frameworks) normally start searching for included dlls from application directory your application will load proxy "d3d9.dll".   So by disallowing any third-party files or libraries in your application folder youre protecting your application from basic proxing in platform independent way.

Comment: Detect in working directory would fail in case they place the proxy dll in windows dll folder.